droidscript events error / bug when i declare them on a class
I have a class whit this code


class Widget {

  onstructor(v) {
        this.value = v
  }
  createFilledRange() {
            
        this.btn_plus = app.CreateButton("[fa-plus]", 0.1, 0.05, "FontAwesome")
          
        this.btn_plus.SetOnTouch(() => {
            app.ShowPopup(this.value)
        })
  }
        
}



... and I instantiate the class like this


let termo = new Widget(20)
let shower = new Widget(40)

termo.createFilledRange())
shower.createFilledRange()



If i only instantiate one item i have problem, but when I do it with two objects the value of clicking my button always give me the second object value. That is to say, no matter the button i press, the result is always 40.
On the other hand, if I set the event like this, the program works perfectly


let termo = new Widget(20)
let shower = new Widget(40)

termo.createFilledRange()
termo.btn_plus.SetOnTouch(() => {
    app.ShowPopup(termo.value)
})
shower.createFilledRange()
shower.btn_plus.SetOnTouch(() => {
    app.ShowPopup(shower.value)
})



updated >>>>>
but this doesnt work (maybe this can give a help)


let termo = new Widget(20)

termo.createFilledRange()
termo.btn_plus.SetOnTouch(() => {
    app.ShowPopup(termo.value)
})

termo = new Widget(40)
termo.createFilledRange()
termo.btn_plus.SetOnTouch(() => {
    app.ShowPopup(termo.value)
})



How can i set the event directly on the class?
thanks for all
